# I Minted on Arbitrum - But contract was meant to be on ETH

Tags: mint, arbitrum

I went to mint a contract on ETH today, was a bit of a cluster - I somehow managed to mint it on Arbitrum is there any way the devs are able to get my ETH back. It is only 0.1 ETH but its the principal of it
Check the TX and lmk :)

https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x09f6d8feb4bdfbdb76b28bf6953141c892a8a9de54db4ece0c64541c6002e3da

Comment: You cannot. Once transaction is done, you cannot undone it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, as soon as you mint, said funds are forfeit indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a contract deployed in a EVM compatible chain, it is possible for the *contract's owner* to deploy a recovery contract in the Arbitrum chain and take ownership of the ether.